How would one calculate yield to first call for a debt security which is currently and always callable?
If an asset manager has multiple extended warehouse lines outstanding and each one is currently callable (some with penalties, some without), is it simply the case that a ‘to first call’ performance scenario (for instance, for yield to first call analyses) across the portfolio would show every single line paying off tomorrow?

The issuer usually can't just call tomorrow. Rather, callable securities usually have a call notice period, typically 30 days, sometimes more. Also in your yield calculations, use the correct cash flows, e.g. if the call price is other than par, or includes some penalties or fees, be sure to consider those.

The scenario of analyzing YTC across a portfolio with multiple callable extended warehouse lines involves considering the earliest date at which each individual line can be called, but it doesn’t necessarily mean that every line will pay off tomorrow.
